# Dynamic Database Connections with Zend framework 2?

Tags: php, database, dynamic, zend-framework2

How we can develop a rest api with dynamic database connection by checking an existing database in zf2?
Now i have developed a rest api with one database. My requirement is the database connection (remote db)should change by usertype after checking the existing database. Database details comes from one main database. How this possible in ZF2? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
       //Add a service on factories in config/autoload/global.php

      'dynamic-db-adapter' => function($sm) {
       $request = $sm->get('request');
       $key= $request->getPost('key');
     //Master Db Adapter
      $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
  //Make db adapter based on key. Based on key you can fetch db credentials from master db
     $dynamic_adapter = $common->fncGetAdapterObject($dbAdapter, $key);
      return $dynamic_adapter ;
      }
```

Comment: What point is not clear for you?please tell me i will explain

Comment: And use this adapter only ("dynamic-db-adapter") for all db functionality.